# SliderExtender Reset

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would think this would be simple... or that atleast someone else would desire the same thing, but I am unable to find any documentation anywhere...

I have a form with 7 text boxes and 5 sliderextenders on 5 of them... im using jquery, and a client side input button to reset the form on the client side... i can reset the values of the text boxes easily, but the sliderextenders will not reset to their default position or their "actual" value... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omg.. pretty easy actually.

```
function ResetForm() { $find('behaviorID').set_Value(0); }
```